# temporary variable value changes after initiating

Tags: c#, .net, class, wcf

```
//save the current origin value        
Employee temp = Origin;
// do some staff with origin and it changes the origin value.

//restore origin to the temp
Origin = temp;
//here i expected the origin value restore to the temp but it doesn't.
```

temp value changes with origin value. in other word both temp and origin has the same values!!!

I want to save `Origin` value and the restore it, but if `origin` changes the `temp` changes too. Its like compiler doesn't  initiate `temp`.

I guess its a real fundamental developing knowledge but i couldn't find the answer. so sorry about that.

**UPDATE**
so far i tried these but non of them worked:

```
var temp = Origin; 
object tmp = temp; 
Origin = (Employee)tmp;

var temp = new Employee(); 
temp = Origin;
Origin = temp;
```

finally as dear @erikscandola said I copy all properties one by one in to the `temp` object and its worked. but that was very hard(assuming the `Employee` is real big object). is there a better way to do such a thing? it really seems easy.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between [value types and reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) and you will understand what is wrong with your code. (Hint - it seems you are using reference types)

Comment: Post lacks [MCVE], so can't really be answered, but you likely find explanation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c.

Comment: @dotnetom thank you so much. i get it now. its look like both temp and Orgin has the same memory. but how can solve my problem? can i create temp value with its own memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the normal behavior of C#. When you assign an object to another object you assign the same instance. So `temp` and `Origin` have the same pointer. In order to assign `Origin` to `temp` you need to do this in the constructor:

```
public Employee(Employee e){
    // copy all property values
}
```

Then you call the constructor:

```
Employee temp = new Employee(Origin);
```

Now you can do what you want with `Origin` without changing the value of `temp`.

Comment: Thanks. but its sort of impossible!! employee has so many properties. and also i don't have access to the class.

Comment: You can create a method to copu all properties. Initializate a new Employee `Employee temp = new Employee();` then call method to copy all `CopyEmployeed(temp, Origin);`

Answer (score 4):

Both `temp` and `Origin` are reference types, `temp` and `Origin` are pointing to the same memory location on the heap and therefore they have the same value. 
To avoid this create new `Employee` as:

```
var temp = new Employee();
```

This will create a new memory location on the heap and thus having its own different value.

Comment: Thank you. but its not working. i tried this:             var temp = new Employee();
            temp = Origin;

Comment: In such case, you can use copy constructure in which you have to map all properties of emp with properties of temp

Answer (score 0):

Class in `.Net` is Reference Type and when change on of them thay are change.
you can use an Object Temp like this :

```
Employee temp = Origin;

Object tmp = temp;
```

and when you want use , you should cast befor use.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. you mean i do somthing like this: Object temp = Origin; then Origin= Temp?

Comment: Thanks. but it doesnt work. i tried this:             var temp = Origin;
            object tmp = temp;             Origin = (Employee)tmp;